# React Accordion

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm having trouble with a React project.
I wanted to import the Accordion from Bootstrap, but when I use it, it just doesn't show up on the browser.

```
import './App.css';
import { Accordion } from "react-bootstrap"
function App() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing 
              elit. Id fugit amet magnam illum aspernatur ratione 
              blanditiis dolorum, deleniti libero explicabo nisi 
              dicta? Sapiente quo illum voluptatum deserunt 
              explicabo, sint consequatur?
         <Accordion>
             <Accordion.Item eventKey='0'>
                 <Accordion.Header>Item 1</Accordion.Header>
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur 
                  adipisicing elit. Eveniet eos ipsum id 
                  perferendis velit nihil dolorem. Suscipit, 
                  veniam, laudantium vero quaerat maxime debitis 
                  excepturi placeat, sed vel incidunt qui eum.
             </Accordion.Item>
          </Accordion>
       </div>
       );
      }

     export default App;
```

But when I remove the Accordion, the browser displays the text

```
import './App.css';
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Id fugit amet magnam illum aspernatur ratione blanditiis dolorum, deleniti libero explicabo nisi dicta? Sapiente quo illum voluptatum deserunt explicabo, sint consequatur?
    </div>
  );
}
```

I would like to try using the Bootstrap library
and its components (Buttons Accordion Alerts) if this is a problem, I think in the future I could use it with ease

Comment: Did you imprt the [correct stylesheets](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction#stylesheets)?

Comment: Can you please share the code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Never share code as an image! StackOverflow allows you to input code snippets which are copy/pastable.